# when the contents are being added to the html page at the bottom, contents from the top disappears

Tags: html, css

I have created following html form.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
 /* #background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
  background:rgb(233, 227, 227);
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.wrapper .title h1{
  color: #c5ecfd;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact-form{
  display: flex;
}

.input-fields{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.input-fields,
.msg{
  width: 48%;
}






.input-fields .input,
.msg textarea{
  margin: 10px 0;
  
  border: 0px;
  /*#border: 2px solid #c5ecfd;*/
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  
  
  

  
  
}

.msg textarea{
  height: 212px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #c5ecfd;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #c5ecfd;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: #c5ecfd;
}

.btn {
    background: #39b7dd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}


input[type=submit] {padding:15px; background:#ccc; border:0 none;
display: block;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: #39b7dd;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase; }



input[type=file] {
    padding-top:15px; 
padding-bottom:15px;
/*#display: block;*/

  color: black;
  width: 100%;
 }

input[type=radio] {
    padding-top:15px; 
padding-bottom:15px;
/*#display: block;*/
float:left;
position:inline;
  color: black;
padding-right:15px;
 }


.radioOpContainer 
{
/*position:inline;*/
    padding-top:15px; 
padding-bottom:15px;
}

.radioOpContainer input{
    /*#padding-right:15px;*/
    margin-right:20px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .contact-form{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .msg textarea{
    height: 80px;
  }
  .input-fields,
  .msg{
    width: 100%;
  }

  
  
}



/*

#fileuploaddiv
{
    padding-top:5px;
}
*/

.label

{
    padding-top:20px;
     font-size: 15px;
}


.error
{
/*font-family: 'Open Sans Regular';*/
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
/*font-size: 1em;*/
font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #c0392b; 
    
    
}


 
  /* ----------------------   */
  
  
 
  
  .table_row
  {
  
  padding-top:10px;
    
  }
  
  .cell_wrapper
  {
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  
  .cell 
  {
  
 display:inline-block;
 

  /*float: left;
  width: 50%;  */
  /*outline: 1px dashed black;  */
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
  word-break:break-all;
font-family: Monospace;
 width: 49%;

  }
  

  
  .resultcell 
  {
  
 display:inline-block;
 

  /*float: left;
  width: 50%;  */
  /*outline: 1px dashed black;  */
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
  word-break:break-all;
font-family: Monospace;
 width: 49%;

  }



  
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cell, .resultcell 
  {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
  
  
  .red{
    color: red;   
}
.magenta{
    color: magenta;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Responsive Contact us form Using HTML and CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>contact us form</h1>
  </div>
      <form  th:action="@{/}" th:object="${messageForm}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MqMessageSenderForm">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <div class="input-fields">

                    <div class="label"><p>Queue manager Name: </p></div>
                    <select id="recievedQMname" class="input" th:field="*{recievedQMname}"><option selected="selected" value=""/></select>
                    <div class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('recievedQMname')}" th:errors="*{recievedQMname}"></div>
                    <div class="label"><p>Destination queue Name</p></div>
                    <input type="text" class="input" th:field="*{recievedQname}" id="recievedQname">
                    <div class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('recievedQname')}" th:errors="*{recievedQname}"></div>
                    <div class="label"><p> Select an input method </p></div> 
                    <div class="radioOpContainer"><input type="radio" name="msginputoption" id="fileradio"   checked="checked"    > <label for="fileradio">File</label></div>
                    <div class="radioOpContainer"><input type="radio" name="msginputoption" id="messagetextradio"  >  <label for="messagetextradio">Message text</label></div>
                    </div>

                <div class="msg">
                    <div class="label">Upload files </div>
                    <input type="file"  th:field="*{files}" multiple accept=".txt,.xml" id="files" >
                    <div class="error" th:if="${fileUploadValidationResult != null}"  th:text="'' + ${fileUploadValidationResult} + ''"></div>  
                    <textarea class="input" th:field="*{msgText}" id="msgText"   disabled="disabled" ></textarea>
                    <div class="error" th:if="${textMsgValidationResult != null}"  th:text="'' + ${textMsgValidationResult} + ''"></div>
                    <input class="btn" type="submit">   
                </div>
    
            </div>
    </form> 

    
    <div class="table"  th:if="${result != null}">
    <div class="table_row" th:each="mapEntry : ${result}">
    <div class="cell_wrapper">
    <div class="cell" th:text="${mapEntry.key}" >key</div> <div class="resultcell" th:text="${mapEntry.value}">value</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="table"  th:if="${UImessageSentresult != null}">
    <div class="table_row">
    <div class="cell_wrapper">
    <div class="resultcell" style="width: 100%;" th:text="${UImessageSentresult}" >UImessageSentresult</div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

when messages sent status results are being added to the bottom of the page, portion from the top is disappearing from the browser( not even able to scroll to the top -I have attached an image as well) I have added the code into jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lmatrix47/nux3h1cd/1/

I'm not a UI expert, Can someone point out the where the problem is[image: Top of the page dissapears when contents are being added to the bottom]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Responsive Contact us form Using HTML and CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>contact us form</h1>
  </div>
      <form  th:action="@{/}" th:object="${messageForm}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MqMessageSenderForm">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <div class="input-fields">

                    <div class="label"><p>Queue manager Name: </p></div>
                    <select id="recievedQMname" class="input" th:field="*{recievedQMname}"><option selected="selected" value=""/></select>
                    <div class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('recievedQMname')}" th:errors="*{recievedQMname}"></div>
                    <div class="label"><p>Destination queue Name</p></div>
                    <input type="text" class="input" th:field="*{recievedQname}" id="recievedQname">
                    <div class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('recievedQname')}" th:errors="*{recievedQname}"></div>
                    <div class="label"><p> Select an input method </p></div> 
                    <div class="radioOpContainer"><input type="radio" name="msginputoption" id="fileradio"   checked="checked"    > <label for="fileradio">File</label></div>
                    <div class="radioOpContainer"><input type="radio" name="msginputoption" id="messagetextradio"  >  <label for="messagetextradio">Message text</label></div>
                    </div>

                <div class="msg">
                    <div class="label">Upload files </div>
                    <input type="file"  th:field="*{files}" multiple accept=".txt,.xml" id="files" >
                    <div class="error" th:if="${fileUploadValidationResult != null}"  th:text="'' + ${fileUploadValidationResult} + ''"></div>  
                    <textarea class="input" th:field="*{msgText}" id="msgText"   disabled="disabled" ></textarea>
                    <div class="error" th:if="${textMsgValidationResult != null}"  th:text="'' + ${textMsgValidationResult} + ''"></div>
                    <input class="btn" type="submit">   
                </div>
    
            </div>
    </form> 

    
    <div class="table"  th:if="${result != null}">
    <div class="table_row" th:each="mapEntry : ${result}">
    <div class="cell_wrapper">
    <div class="cell" th:text="${mapEntry.key}" >key</div> <div class="resultcell" th:text="${mapEntry.value}">value</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="table"  th:if="${UImessageSentresult != null}">
    <div class="table_row">
    <div class="cell_wrapper">
    <div class="resultcell" style="width: 100%;" th:text="${UImessageSentresult}" >UImessageSentresult</div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrapper div is given as absolute. when comparing to parent element height is less that's the reason for hiding the content you can
either change .wrapper to relative instead of absolute
or you can add scroll for wrapper.

Try the below code

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    transform: initial;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lijo , All good now!!